# Fundir dos $(document).on('click' en uno ajax

Tags: ajax, autocompletar

tengo un script de autocompletado ajax y estoy intentando fundir dos `$(document).on('click'` en uno para que al hacer un solo click se copien los dos a la vez en sus correspondientes campos pero no lo consigo es posible?

```
$(document).on('click', '.datalistdes', function(){
                $('#nombre1').val($(this).text());
                $('#Listdes').fadeOut();

        }).on('click', '.linkdata', function(){
                $('#nombre2').val($(this).text());
                $('#Listdes').fadeOut();

        });

<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::text('nombre1', null, ['class' => 'from-control', 'id' => 'nombre1']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::text('nombre2', null, ['class' => 'from-control', 'id' => 'nombre2']) }}
</div>
```

Ahora mismo me funciona bien al hacer clic en uno me lo rellena y al hacer clic en el otro también pero lo que necesito es que se rellenen las dos con un solo clic.

Comment: Quieres disparar el mismo evento click para dos componentes diferentes?

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir un [mcve]? Sólo te falta un poco de HTML para que comprendamos bien tu duda

Comment: Si Mario L exactamente eso

Comment: Ahora mismo Pablo Lozano pero quieres decir el formulario ?

Answer (score 0):

Hice un ejemplo con dos botones usando tus clases, la idea es agregar una clase en comun que tengan los dos selectores y a esa clase en común asignarle el evento click y luego evaluar cual de los dos haz pinchado:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.clase-en-comun', function(){

  if($(this).hasClass("datalistdes")){
    
    alert("Haz clikeado datalistdes y el selector que voy a instanciar es #nombredes");
    $('#nombredes').val($(this).text());
    
  }else if($(this).hasClass("linkdata")){
    
    alert("Haz clikeado linkdata y el selector que voy a instanciar es #linkdes")
    $('#linkdes').val($(this).text());
  
  }
  
  $('#Listdes').fadeOut();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="datalistdes clase-en-comun">datalistdes</button>

<button class="linkdata clase-en-comun">linkdata</button>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda y tu tiempo David lo que quiero es enviar los 2 al hacer click en uno

Comment: como enviar? hacer un ajax?

Comment: si como enviar los dos datos a sus respectivos input en un solo clic con ajax

Comment: @LendyRodriguezSilva datalistdes y linkdata son datalist?

Comment: en realidad no son clases simplemente

Comment: si pero que tipo de obteto son? un datalist? select? input?

Comment: la clase las añado a <li> dentro de un div

Answer (score 0):

Como alternativa a la solucion de David podrias hacer lo siguiente:

```
$(document).on('click', '.datalistdes, .linkdata', function(){
    // logica que coloca el text al input que deseas
    $('#Listdes').fadeOut();
});
```

La logica que selecciona al elemento y le coloca el text del input variaria dependiendo de como este armado el html.

[JQuery Multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Comment: el problema es que necesito que lo inserte cada uno en su input

Comment: Podrias editar en tu pregunta para mostrar un ejemplo de el html que tienes?

Comment: Ya lo edite intente que se entienda un poco mejor disculpen

Answer (score 0):

En base a la respuesta de cavpollo, podrías completarla de la siguiente forma:

```
$(document).on('click', '.datalistdes, .linkdata', function(){
    // logica que coloca el text al input que deseas

    if($(this).attr('class') == "linkdata"){
        $('#nombre2').val($(this).text());
                $('#Listdes').fadeOut();
    }else{
        $('#nombre1').val($(this).text());
                $('#Listdes').fadeOut();
    }

    //Para cargar el valor en los dos inputs
    /*
    $('#nombre2').val($(this).text());
    $('#Listdes').fadeOut();
    $('#nombre1').val($(this).text());
    $('#Listdes').fadeOut();*/
});
```

Puse las dos opciones, es decir, para cargar un input según donde se haya hecho el click y para cargar los dos inputs.